# How to redirect with $http_post AngularJS + Laravel ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

This morning I discover the $http_method and it's fantastic ! but.... I have one problem another time XD

First I send the content correct and the DataBasae was update correctly but when I try to update the site with the following code I have an error.

```
 $timeout(function() {
                $location.path('/');
              });
```

My code is this

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
                $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'todos',
                    data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
                    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
                })                
            };
```

The controler in my files route.php in Laravel is the next:

```
Route::post('todos', function()
    {
        $user = new Nodes;
        $user->name = Input::get("name");
        $user->save();

    });
```

I don't know how to update the webpage when I send the content in the form ... any solutions about this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, make you you inject $location as a service dependency and then add a then function which determines what happens when the server responds with a success

```
app.controller('ctrlName', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location){
    $scope.processForm = function() {
            $http({
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : 'todos',
                data    : $.param($scope.formData),  // pass in data as strings
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
            }).then(function(response){
                //successfully posted data
                $location.path('/');
            }, function(response){
                //error has occurred
            })                
        }; 

}])
```